# File browser is not opening after AJAX call in Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, firefox

The programmatic click on a file input after a successful AJAX call does not open the file browser in Firefox, but it works fine in Chrome.
I have this issue on **82.0.3 (64-bit), Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0** and **83.0 (64-bit) Mozilla Firefox for Windows - Currently the latest version**.
I am not sure whether I am doing something wrong here or it's a bug with Firefox. Please help me out.

Here are the code samples:

ReactJS: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-napier-32n1o?file=/src/UploadOption/UploadOption.js

Javascript: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-sea-yv67c?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a Firefox popup blocker issue. If you change `dom.disable_open_during_load` to `false` in `about:config`, then it starts working.

So Firefox seems to think that the async click() call is not part of the user interaction, and is thus blocking the popup.

I've filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1678389 on this, and I sent a patch.

In terms of workarounds, the popup blocker state is preserved across timeouts, so something like this should work:

```
  var ready = false;
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      ready = true;
    }
  };

  setTimeout(function tryReady() {
    // Does not open file explorer in mozilla firefox,
    // but the function is triggered!
    if (ready) {
      openExplorer();
    } else {
      setTimeout(tryReady, 500);
    }
  }, 500);
```

Comment: Yes. Setting **dom.disable_open_during_load** to **false** opens the file browser. Thanks for filing a bug on this. I'll watch on that. But for now I need to find a workaround for my app.

Comment: Thanks for adding a workaround. But it is inconsistent. It doesn't work if there is a slight delay (~1 second) in the AJAX response.